# I am struggling with how to add icons on buttons and add image to a dialog in MFC cpp m new to mfc

Tags: mfc

i don t know how like i serached everywhere
m trying to show a picture in my dialogue and also trying to add little icons on my buttons

idk what to do, i copied and pasted this code in initdialog function:

```cpp
pp = new CStatic;
pp->Create(_T(""), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BITMAP, CRect(10, 10, 100, 100), this);
pp->SetDlgCtrlID(IDC_STATIC_PICTURE);

// Load and set the image for the dynamic picture control
CImage image;
if (SUCCEEDED(image.Load(_T("OIP.jpg"))))
{
    CRect rect;
    pp->GetClientRect(&rect);

    // Create a compatible DC for the image
    CDC dc;
    dc.CreateCompatibleDC(pp->GetDC());

    // Select the image into the DC
    CBitmap bmp;
    bmp.Attach(image.Detach());
    dc.SelectObject(&bmp);

    // Stretch the image to fit the control
    pp->GetDC()->StretchBlt(0, 0, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), &dc,
                            0, 0, image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight(), SRCCOPY);
}
```

plus I wrote this : `CStatic *pp;` in my dialogue header file I also switched the picture control type from frame to bitmap

Comment: For the buttons with icons check out [CBitmapButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbitmapbutton-class?view=msvc-170)

Comment: For the picture control it's not enough to draw the picture once, you'll want to use a class that stores the bitmap and can redraw it every time a `WM_DRAW` message is received.

Comment: Use `CMFCButton` class in the resource editor. Has built-in support for images. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcbutton-class?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you create the controls programmatically? They are for your dialog class, therefore they could simply be placed in the dialog resource: a static control with the `SS_BITMAP` style set (done easily in VS's Dialog Resource Editor) and a push-button control, possibly with the `BS_BITMAP` style set (check the Win32 documentation to find what effects setting or not setting this style has). And the way you draw your controls is wrong, you should put the images into the controls using messages like `STM_SETIMAGE` and `BM_SETIMAGE` (or their MFC wrappers) in `OnInitDialog()` (once), instead of responding to paint requests. Your implementation here is wrong too, because paint requests are not received during a dialog's initialization, they are received later, as a result of "invalidation" (caused by the user or by the app) or by state or style changes. I think you don't even need to define variables for your controls (like `CStatic *pp;`), you can simply call the [`SendDlgItemMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-senddlgitemmessagea) function in `OnInitDialog()`, to send the aforementioned messages to your controls.